# Firebase related fields population

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to recreate a Mongoose + Express app with Firebase + Express. But I trying to "populate" (like Mongoose) related fields with reference model but it is kinda manually and maybe there is a shorter way to achieve this.

In Mongoose you just code `Ticket.find({}).populate('category')` and it gives you the related object automatically mapped. I don't know how to achieve this in Firebase ORM. My code looks like this but is not populating the category properly:

```js
export const tickets = (req, res) => {
    // First model reference
    const ref = database.ref('tickets');
    ref.once('value', snapshot => {
        let tickets: object = [];
        if (snapshot.val()) {
            const obj = snapshot.val();
            tickets = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
                const ticket = { key, ...obj[key] };
                if (ticket.category) {
                    // Related model reference
                    const categoriesRef = database.ref(`categories/${ticket.category}`);
                    categoriesRef.once('value', snapshot => {
                        if (snapshot.val()) {
                            ticket.category = { key: snapshot.key, ...snapshot.val() };
                        }   
                    }).catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: error.message }));
                }
                return ticket;
            });
        }
        res.json(tickets);
    }).catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: error.message }));
};
```

This code returns all tickets. They should include their related "category" according to its key. Do you know a shorter way?

Comment: There is no concept of a JOIN statement in Firebase, so what you do doesn't look overly long to me. Do you have any problem when you run this code?

Comment: `let tickets: object = [];` should be `let tickets = [] as any[];`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, yes, `category` is not being filled. I guess this happens because JS returns the ticket before it gets its category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend exclusively working with the Promise API rather than callbacks as it will make handling errors easier. Plus, in your code you are also mixing the callback and Promise APIs together which will result in some inconsistencies.

The reason why your categories aren't included, is because you are returning the `ticket` object, before the `category` field has been updated.

```js
if (ticket.category) {
    // Related model reference
    const categoriesRef = database.ref(`categories/${ticket.category}`);
    categoriesRef.once('value', snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val()) {
            ticket.category = { key: snapshot.key, ...snapshot.val() };
        }   
    }).catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: error.message }));
}
return ticket; // this is evaluated before any of the above asynchronous stuff
```

To solve this, you must return a Promise with the "assembled" ticket.

```js
if (!ticket.category) {
  return Promise.resolve(ticket);
}

return categoriesRef.once('value')
  .then(categorySnapshot => {
    const category = categorySnapshot.val();
    category.key = categorySnapshot.key;
    ticket.category = category;

    return ticket;
  });
```

#### Code

Mixing this into your code and removing some syntatic sugar for performance gains, results in:

```js
export const tickets = (req, res) => {
  const categoriesRef = database.ref('categories'); // Changed: moved to start of function
  const ref = database.ref('tickets');

  ref.once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      const ticketPromises = []; // array of promises to assembled tickets
      snapshot.forEach(ticketSnapshot => { // NOTE: This is `DataSnapshot#forEach()` not `Array#forEach()`
        // changed: val() creates a fresh object, so we can modify
        //          it without using the spread operator
        const ticket = ticketSnapshot.val(); 
        ticket.key = ticketSnapshot.key;

        if (!ticket.category) {
          // no further assembly required, return the ticket as is
          ticketPromises.push(Promise.resolve(ticket));
          return;
        }

        const ticketPromise = categoriesRef.child(ticket.category).once('value')
          .then(categorySnapshot => {
            // same as before, no need for spread operator
            const category = ticket.category = categorySnapshot.val();
            category.key = categorySnapshot.key;

            return ticket; // return assembled ticket
          });

        ticketPromises.push(ticketPromise);
      });

      return Promise.all(ticketPromises); // wait for all tickets
    })
    .then(tickets => {
      res.json(tickets); // return tickets to client
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
    });
};
```

#### Code w/ Value Caching

Because you are also likely to request the same category several times whilst not modifying the data, you can also cache the category `{...data, key}` objects to save on memory and marginal compute time using the below code:

```js
export const tickets = (req, res) => {
  const categoryCachedValues = new CachedValues(database.ref('categories'), "key");
  const ref = database.ref('tickets');

  ref.once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      const ticketPromises = [];
      snapshot.forEach(ticketSnapshot => { // NOTE: This is `DataSnapshot#forEach()` not `Array#forEach()`
        const ticket = ticketSnapshot.val(); 
        ticket.key = ticketSnapshot.key;

        if (!ticket.category) {
          // no further assembly required, return the ticket as is
          ticketPromises.push(Promise.resolve(ticket));
          return;
        }

        const ticketPromise = categoryCachedValues.get(ticket.category)
          .then(categoryData => {
            ticket.category = categoryData;
            return ticket; // return assembled ticket
          });

        ticketPromises.push(ticketPromise);
      });

      return Promise.all(ticketPromises); // wait for all tickets
    })
    .then(tickets => {
      res.json(tickets); // return tickets to client
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
    });
};

class CachedValues {
  constructor(ref, keyFieldName) {
    this._ref = ref;
    this._promises = {};
    if (keyFieldName) {
      this._extractData = (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        data[keyFieldName] = data.key;
        return data;
      };
    } else {
      this._extractData = (snapshot) => snapshot.val();
    }
  }

  get(path) {
    if (!this._promises[path]) {
      this._promises[path] = this._ref.child(path)
        .once('value')
        .then(this._extractData);
    }
    return this._promises[path];
  }
}
```

Comment: the first option worked fine. I might need cached values but I have to understand them better. Thank you.